# How to add x.509 certificate subject as a user to Mongodb 3.4 by Node.js MongoDB Driver API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, x509

I need to add users to my MongoDB 3.4 Replica Set using an Node.js application that already has the Node.js MongoDB Driver API package.

The problem is: [The API documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Admin.html#addUser) doesn't cover how to [add x.509 Certificate subject as a User](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/).

Does anyone know how to do that? In other words, I need a Node.js mechanism/API which I can use to perform the mongodb command below:

```
mongo --host mongo-node-0
use admin
db.getSiblingDB("$external").runCommand(
{createUser: "emailAddress=foo@bar.com,CN=admin,OU=Clients,O=FOO,L=Dublin,ST=Ireland,C=IE",
roles: [
{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
{ role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
{ role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db:"admin" },
{ role: "clusterAdmin",  db: "admin" }
]})
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least your attempts like `var db = new Db('$external'); db.command(....` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Mongo](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) documentation, on Node, execute a command hash against MongoDB. This lets you access any commands not available through the API on the server.

```
command(selector[, options], callback)
    Arguments:  

        selector (object) – the command hash to send to the server, ex: {ping:1}.
        [options] (object) – additional options for the command.
        callback (function) – this will be called after executing this method. The command always return the whole result of the command as the second parameter.

    Returns:    

    null
```

So, you can try it:

```
 var db = new Db('$external', new MongoServer('localhost', 27017));
 db.open(function(err, db) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }

   db.command({
     createUser: "emailAddress=foo@bar.com,CN=admin,OU=Clients,O=FOO,L=Dublin,ST=Ireland,C=IE",
     roles: [
       { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
       { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
       { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db:"admin" },
       { role: "clusterAdmin",  db: "admin" }
     ]}, function(err, result){
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
       }
       console.log(result)

       db.close();
   });
 });
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, thank you so much! Actually I was looking for a native addUser support for x.509, but looks like it doesn't exist. Anyway, what you provided is exactly what I was needing! I tested your code and after some fixes (please, see edition), it worked perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: Hi,
Edited again, because looks like the last reviewers (users/36938/taylan-aydinli, users/488397/steve and users/2057091/aserre) just rejected it without realize the current source code has bugs, and will not work. I sent the edition again with the corrections which will do this code work. Hope not be rejected again. :/